# How import module bluetooth on Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm a beginner on developing Android application and I'm using Java , my problem is that when I tap "import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter"  it happen like this :

[This is a part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm3jJ.png)

Comment: Its Gray in Color only because you are not using it in that activity... Best auto import the package or use bluetoothAdapter in the java file and on error Press **Alt+Enter** for windows or **Option+Return** in mac and select import the bluetooth package it will be working just fine !!

Answer (score 0):

you have placed `import` on top of some file, but its grayed-out because you aren't using it in code in this file. you are using `AppCompatActivity` (probably extending it) and `Bundle` (probably for overriden `onCreate(...)` which takes `Bundle` as input), so they are white informing you that they are used. grayed-out `import`s aren't used, so these lines are unnecessary and may be removed

I suggest you to NOT manipulate imports on top of Java files. these should be placed automatically by IDE, or IDE at least will suggest auto-import. without your grayed-out `import` line when you use `BluetoothAdapter` inside some method, e.g. `onCreate` then IDE will suggest or even automatically `import` needed dependendy for you